# Cambiar de formulario de registro al de iniciar sesión con HTML

Tags: html, firebase

Estoy creando un `login`, pero tengo al final la opción de que si ingreso al registro pero ya tiene cuenta, que pueda cambiar con un clic a el formulario de `login`.

En pocas palabras, en la imagen se ve que puedo dar clic en donde dice `registrate`, y quiero que me lleve al `form` del `login`.

```
'''<!-- Modal registro -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="registromodal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelregistro">
          Registrarse
        </h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="login-page">
          <div class="form">
            <img src="imagenes/valetparking.jpg" height="100px" alt="" />
            <h1>Bienvenidos</h1>

            <form id="registrarse-form" method="post">
              <input
                id="signup-email"
                type="email"
                placeholder="Correo electronico "
                required
              />
              <input
                id="signup-password"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Contraseña"
                required
              />

              <button class="formbutton" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
              <p class="message">
                Ya tienes una cuenta?
                <a href="#loginmodal">Inicia Sesión</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

'''
quiero que al dar clic en registrate me lleve a otro formulario

[image: no tienes una cuenta? registrate.]

Answer (score 1):

ya logre resolverlo con este codigo de la siguiente forma

```
<p style="color: black;" class="message"> No tienes una cuenta?
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#registromodal">Registrarse</button></p>
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien (que no creo), solo necesitas hacer el botón de "registrarse":

```html
<a id="identifica" href="dirección de tu formulario"><img src="imagen (opcional" alt="Regresar"/>Registrarse</a>
```

¿O lo que necesitas es tener una doble función al hacer click en el botón?

Comment: hola mira el href se que debo poner la direccion de mi formulario. pero mi formulario es  de tipo form y esta en la misma pagina index.html pero yo lo tengo identificado con ID entonces no se como hacer que al hacer clic en ese boton registrate me lleve al otro formulario por medio de el ID

Comment: Lo puedes poner fuera del form:

Comment: <form>Aquí tu formulario</form><a>aquí tu botón</a> Ya solo lo debes acomodar con css

Comment: no nada no me da poniendola afuera del form.  solo me hace falta es llamar al otro form por medio de ID

Comment: no le pongas el mismo id y también que no sea de type=' sumbit'

Comment: <a id='otra' href="dirección url de tu formulario"><img src="imagen (opcional" alt="Regresar"/>Registrarse</a>